# Mountain bike shorts for commute

Tags: commuter, clothes, shorts

I was recently given padded mountain bike shorts. Are mountain bike shorts good for commute? (around 11 km one-way)

Comment: Do you change at work?  Are such shorts acceptable at work ?

Comment: I go to school :) We have changing rooms and there are no such limitations

Answer (score 12):

Mountain bike shorts are ideal for commuting. If they fit, are comfortable and you like the look of them, you won't find a better commute short.  If you a fast rider, over 11km the extra drag of baggies will cost you a few seconds over a lycra skin suit.

However, if you are riding a road bike, you are breaking [Rule #18](https://www.velominati.com/) :)

Comment: Thanks mattnz! I'm not a very fast rider (my max speed has been 33kmph :) ), so I don't think that it might be an issue of paramount importance. But I carry a backpack over my shoulders to school, so the weight makes the ride a bit uncomfortable. I'm hoping that the padded shorts provide me with some comfort. My bike is theoretically a mountain bike, but I recently swapped out 2.1 for 1.75 slicks. It has a front fork

Answer (score 5):

For commutes of that sort of distance, just wear whatever is comfortable, and that you've got enough of to stay fresh. For me, when I started, that was gym shorts and tops. Padding shouldn't be necessary over that distance, but feel free to wear it if you like.